# Comparing 2 arrays in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to compare one sorted descending array and one unsorted array in javascript and unsorted array elements location in the sorted one.

so if the number of elements is 7 in sorted array

```
[100,90,80,70,60,50,40]
```

and number of elements in unsorted array is 4 unsorted array is

```
[200,10,55,65]
```

then the output will be

```
1
8
6
5
```

Comment: How did you get 1 8 6 5 for your output..? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Why will the output be `1 8 6 5`?

Comment: Is that output supposed to be something like the index at which you'd need to insert the new elements?  It's not, exactly, because JS is zero-based, but it looks as though it's something like that.

Comment: when 200 is encountered in array it is sent at index 1 which makes the array 200 100 90 80 70 60 50 40.for 10 it goes to end of array makes it at position 8.for 55 it goes to position 6 and for 65 it goes to position 5.Kindly do not make changes to the original array. I just want to know the index of the other array elements in previous one

Comment: Please review [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to find the index (one-based) of where each element would fit into the sorted array. You should be able to do this with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
let arr = [100,90,80,70,60,50,40]
let a2 = [200,10,55,65]

let indexes = a2.map(n => {
    // find the first place in arr where it's less than n
    let ind = arr.findIndex(i => i < n)  

    // if n wasn't found, it is smaller than all items: return length + 1
    return (ind === -1) ? arr.length + 1 : ind  + 1
})
console.log(indexes)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the return part??

Comment: Sure @vinayak_shahdeo thats a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It says if `ind === -1` just return the length of the array +1 otherwise return the `ind +1`. `ind` will be -1 if the number you're looking at is smaller than all items int the array (such as 10 in this example). In that case `findIndex()` doesn't find the index because there are no smaller elements. So it returns -1. The ternary operator lets us test for that special case and return the right value.